# cambiar el contenido de un componente dependiendo de la ruta angular

Tags: angular

esto haciendo una pagina web pero soy nuevo en angular, mi pregunta es como hago para reutilizar un componente pero cambiando su contenido,por ejemplo tengo un componente header en el cual hay un botón  iniciar sesión, pero una vez el usuario sea logueado el contenido de este header debe cambiar, ahora debe decir cerrar sesión. podría simplemente crear otro header y ya , pero pues la idea es usar el que ya tengo y reutilizarlo.

Comment: Hola Juanse. Necesitaremos más detalles para poder ayudar. Tu código, lo que has intentado, etc. Puedes visitar el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para obtener información acerca de [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Podrias crear una funcion en el componente que devuelva si esta logueado o no, y con ngif="isLogout()" mostrar las etiquetas que quieras en html.

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener codigo te recomendaria que crees una variable de entrada Input() en la cual le pases un valor para poder identificar quien lo esta llamando y apartir de esos con un ngIf mostrar o esconder contenido